# Using .htaccess to forward all routes except one to home page for react-router v4

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

I am using `create-react-app` and `react-router v4`. I have a site with many paths, however, one path is a literal path to a folder called `assets` where images, icons, etc are served.

The site structure is like this:

```
.. [root]
assets [dir]
index.html [file]
```

However, I have many virtual URLs that point to the `index.html` of the CRA app. How can I use `.htaccess` to forward all requests except those in `assets` to the `index.html` file?

Or, is there a better/best practice for handling this scenario?

I have tried this but it gives a 500 error.

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Forward to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Forward to React
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets)(/|$)
```

By this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(assets/?|$)
```

Because you already excluded `assets` directory but still this `^(.*)$` will capture any thing else even a request that have passed this rule and that will make looping.

**Note:** clear browser cache then test

Comment: Unfortunately this causes the same 500 error. Could it be the combination of the https rewrite? It seems to not throw a 500 error on my localhost.